# Não está caindo no if de acordo com o número ser maior ou menor

Tags: javascript, node.js, if

O programa que almejo criar deve retornar um array com número de recordes alcançados de uma lista de pontuações e o número da posição da menor pontuação, respectivamente. Porém, ele retorna algo diferente.

```
let stringPontuacoes = "10, 20, 4, 8, 9, 22, 12, 43, 22"


function avaliaPontuacoes (stringPontuacoes) {
    let pontuacoes = stringPontuacoes.split(", ")
    let qtdQuebraDeRecords = 0
    let piorJogo = 1
    let maiorPontuacao = pontuacoes[0]
    let menorPontuacao = pontuacoes[0]

    for (let i = 1; i < pontuacoes.length; i++) {
        if(pontuacoes[i] > maiorPontuacao) {
            maiorPontuacao = pontuacoes[i]
            qtdQuebraDeRecords++ 
        }else if (pontuacoes[i] < menorPontuacao) {
            menorPontuacao = pontuacoes[i]
            piorJogo = i+1;
        }
    }
    return [qtdQuebraDeRecords, piorJogo]
}

console.log(avaliaPontuacoes(stringPontuacoes))
```

O código retorna "[ 4, 1 ]", em vez de "[ 3, 3 ]". Gostaria muito da ajuda de vocês para descobrir como solucionar esse problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está guardando texto em vez de número, aí faz operações matemáticas e comparações com essa informação o que dá errado, então tem que converter para número antes de fazer isto. Muita coisa poderia dar errado, mas parece que você tem controle sobre o formato então não farei maiores verificações.

```js
function avaliaPontuacoes (stringPontuacoes) {
    let pontuacoes = stringPontuacoes.split(", ");
    let qtdQuebraDeRecords = 0;
    let piorJogo = 1;
    let maiorPontuacao = pontuacoes[0];
    let menorPontuacao = pontuacoes[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < pontuacoes.length; i++) {
        let pontuacao = parseInt(pontuacoes[i]);
        if (pontuacao > maiorPontuacao) {
            maiorPontuacao = pontuacao;
            qtdQuebraDeRecords++;
        } else if (pontuacao < menorPontuacao) {
            menorPontuacao = pontuacao;
            piorJogo = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return [qtdQuebraDeRecords, piorJogo];
}

console.log(avaliaPontuacoes("10, 20, 4, 8, 9, 22, 12, 43, 22"));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/SplitStringByNumbers.js).